# How do I append two columns from csv file in list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, append

My code is -

```
df=pd.read_csv("file path")
l1=[]
l2=[]
for i in range(0,len(df['unions']),len(df['district'])):
    l1.append((df['unions'][i], df['district'][i]))
    l2.append(({"entities": [(0,len(df['unions'][i]),df['subdistrict'][i])]}))

TRAIN_DATA=list(zip(l1,l2))
print(TRAIN_DATA)
```

Result I got - `[(('Dhansagar', 'Bagerhat'), {'entities': [(0, 9, 'Sarankhola')]})]`

But I want to get result is this format -

```
[(('Dhansagar Bagerhat'), {'entities': [(0, 9, 'Sarankhola')]})]
```

Basically no comma in between Dhansagar Bagerhat. How do I do it? Also, why am I getting only one result? It seems like my loop is not working.

Comment: Something like `l1.append((df['unions'][i] + " " + df['district'][i],))`?

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data and your expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
    l1.append((df['unions'][i], df['district'][i]))
```

Try:

```
    l1.append(' '.join((df['unions'][i], df['district'][i])))
```

Or:

```
    l1.append((df['unions'][i] + " " + df['district'][i]))
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfectly. But I am getting only one value when I am printing the TRAIN_DATA. Why isn't my loop is working for all the values in the column?